# SQLite Error Code 17

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

One of my tables in my SQLite database is returning this error code below:

> sqlite returned: error code = 17, msg = prepared statement aborts at
>   32[sql statement]

As far as I know, the data was successfully inserted. Is this something I should be concerned about? Or is it just a false error? Based on [this](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/c_abort.html) post, it says:

> The database schema changed

What exactly does it mean? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try insetting more elements it seems false error, once you inserted values your database schema recognized and stops giving this false error..

Answer (score 1):

I'm getting the same error. Are you dropping your database and then re-populating it? This "warning" appears when I wipe out my database and then insert about 200 rows again ... but all works fine. It's strange. There is a [thread](http://sqlite.1065341.n5.nabble.com/database-schema-has-changed-td210.html) in the sqlite forum about this.