# How can I fix SQLite error code 17 when running SELECT statement on empty table in C#?

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite

The following error is appearing in my debug log:

`SQLite error (17): statement aborts at 11: [SELECT car_id, car_name FROM car_info] Database schema has changed.`

I am running the above SELECT statement on an empty table that has the schema `car_id CHAR(32) NOT NULL, car_name TEXT`. Despite the error the command still completes without throwing an exception, however how do I rid myself of this error in my debug log?

I have checked on the [Sqlite forms](https://sqlite.org/forum/forumpost/c1798f77ef) and this post on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11152740/sqlite-error-code-17) but there doesn't seem to be a cause or a fix.

What I've already tried:

- I tried running a `SELECT * FROM car_info`, but I get the same error.
- I tried inserting a row into the car_info table before executing the Select statement, but I get the same error.
- I checked the schema of the car_info table when it was created and the schema after the Select command has been run, but the schema remains unchanged.

Comment: What version of SQLite are you using?

Comment: @Mark SQLite 3.36.0.